# Prestashop module installs but does not work as expected

Tags: prestashop

I have a prestashop plugin that adds an extra tab to the product page:

```
<?php

// Disable direct addressing to the script:
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

//Create module class:
class producttab extends Module {

//Class constructor that contains its configuration:
public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = "producttab"; //Module name
    $this->tab = "front_office_features"; //Tab with the module in Prestashop back-office modules list
    $this->version = "1.0"; // Module version
    $this->author = "BelVG";  // Module author 
    parent::__construct();
    $this->displayName = $this->l("Product Tab"); // Module title
    $this->description = $this->l("Module creates a new tab on the frontend product page "); // Module description 
}

//Module installation-method:
public function install()
{
    return (parent::install()
            AND $this->registerHook('productTab') //Register productTab hook that will display the tab button
            AND $this->registerHook('productTabContent') //Register productTabContent hook that will display the tab content
            );
}

//Module deinstallation-method:
public function uninstall()
{
    return (parent::uninstall()
            AND $this->unregisterHook('productTab')
            AND $this->unregisterHook('productTabContent')); // Delete all hooks, registered by the  module 
}

//Method will be called while performing the "ProductTab" hook (tab buttons generation):
public function hookProductTab($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    //Call the template containing the HTML-code ?? our button
    return $this->display(__FILE__ , 'tpl/productTab.tpl');
}

public function hookProductTabContent($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    //Transfer the new tab content into template via smatry
    //( it is optional as far as the content can be assigned directly in the template)
     $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM ps_cms_lang WHERE id_cms =14');

$smarty->assign('content', $result);
    // Call the template containing the HTML-code of our new tab content:
    return $this->display(__FILE__ , 'tpl/productTabContent.tpl');
}

}
?>
```

The module works as expected. I'm trying to adapt the same code to add another tab. For some reason the new module installs but the tab does not appear. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<?php

// Disable direct addressing to the script:
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;

//Create module class:
class jewellerytab extends Module {

//Class constructor that contains its configuration:
public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = "jewellerytab"; //Module name
    $this->tab = "front_office_features"; //Tab with the module in Prestashop back-office modules list
    $this->version = "1.0"; // Module version
    $this->author = "Mike Rifgin";  // Module author 
    parent::__construct();
    $this->displayName = $this->l("jewellery Tab"); // Module title
    $this->description = $this->l("Module creates a new tab on the frontend jewellery page "); // Module description 
}

//Module installation-method:
public function install()
{
    return (parent::install()
            AND $this->registerHook('jewelleryTab') //Register jewelleryTab hook that will display the tab button
            AND $this->registerHook('jewelleryTabContent') //Register jewelleryTabContent hook that will display the tab content
            );
}

//Module deinstallation-method:
public function uninstall()
{
    return (parent::uninstall()
            AND $this->unregisterHook('jewelleryTab')
            AND $this->unregisterHook('jewelleryTabContent')); // Delete all hooks, registered by the  module 
}

//Method will be called while performing the "jewelleryTab" hook (tab buttons generation):
public function hookjewelleryTab($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    //Call the template containing the HTML-code ?? our button
    return $this->display(__FILE__ , 'tpl/jewelleryTab.tpl');
}

public function hookjewelleryTabContent($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    //Transfer the new tab content into template via smatry
    //( it is optional as far as the content can be assigned directly in the template)
     $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM ps_cms_lang WHERE id_cms =14');

$smarty->assign('content', $result);
    // Call the template containing the HTML-code of our new tab content:
    return $this->display(__FILE__ , 'tpl/jewelleryTabContent.tpl');
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no such hooks as jewelleryTab and jewelleryTabContent, you need to work with productTab and productTabContent (which is part of Prestashop core) Here you can find list of hooks for prestahop 1.5 http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5 and some basic info on what hooks in prestashop are http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Understanding+and+using+hooks

You can also try to reach Denis, [author of this extension from BelVG](http://blog.belvg.com/developer-tips-creating-a-tab-on-the-frontend-product-page-in-prestashop.html)

And after this article Denis developed flexible [extension to add extra product tabs](http://module-presta.com/product-tabs.html)

Answer (score 1):

`jewelleryTab` and `jewelleryTabContent` are custom hook.

You need to add these hook to your `.tpl` template file:

```
{hook h='jewelleryTab'}
{hook h='jewelleryTabContent'}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can only use predefined hooks.

***You can use the same hooks as instead of  jewelleryTab and jewelleryTabContent.***

Hopefully the hooks can be reused.

```
public function install()
{
       return (parent::install()
        AND $this->registerHook('productTab') //Register productTab hook that will display the tab button
        AND $this->registerHook('productTabContent') //Register productTabContent hook that will display the tab content
        );
}
```